# I want to know when I'm sorting some objects, in what case is the operator. attrgetter (),or operator.itemgetter()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, operator-keyword

I want to know the difference between them.
for example: sort a list i met the problem:

```
list=[{'name':'david','age':12},{'name':'lily','age':12},{'name':'kee','age':12},{'name':'jimi','age':12}]
```

i use

```
sorted(list,key=operator.attrgetter('name')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'
```

i don't know wether i use attrgetter() or itemgetter()

Comment: `sorted(lst,key=operator.itemgetter("name"))` works all right. `attrgetter` tries to do `object.name`, but you want `object["name"]`. Those are 2 different concepts. `attrgetter` is useful on a list of custom objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre) commented, the two `operator` functions you're asking about do different things. If you do:

```
attrs = attrgettr("foo")
items = itemgetter("foo")
```

Then calling them will give you different results:

```
result = attrs(some_obj) # equivalent to result = some_obj.foo
result = items(some_obj) # equivalent to result = some_obj['foo']
```

You usually won't want to be applying them to the same kinds of objects. If you have a list of indexable objects (like sequences or mappings), then using `itemgetter` to get a specific item from each of them as the `key` in a call to `list.sort` makes a lot of sense. On the other hand, if the objects in the list are not indexable, but instead have useful attributes, using `attrgetter` will work better.

It's not essential to use either of them. You can always use a `lambda` expression to build a callable instead. `itemgetter('foo')` is equivalent to `lambda x: x['foo']` and `attrgetter('foo')` is equivalent to `lambda x: x.foo`. The lambdas may be a little bit slower than the callables you get from the `operator` functions, but probably not by a whole lot. But `lambda`  can do more, if you need a more complicated result (e.g. `lambda x: x['foo'] - x.bar`, for a weird object with both useful attributes and indexable values).